# Can't get register form to save users in database

Tags: php, sql

I've written the following lines of code but i can't seem to find the problem why i can't get the register form to save the users in my DB. I checked my connection everything is running smoothly.
Code:
This is the form

```
 <form method="POST" action = "rprocess.php">
            <h2 class="text-center"><strong>Зачлени</strong> Се</h2>
            <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" value = "<?php if(isset($_POST['signup'])) { echo $_POST['email']; } ?>" placeholder="Е-маил" required></div>
            <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" value = "<?php if(isset($_POST['signup'])) { echo $_POST['username']; } ?>" placeholder="Корисничко Име" required></div>
            <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="firstname" value = "<?php if(isset($_POST['signup'])) { echo $_POST['firstname']; } ?>" placeholder="Име" required></div>
            <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="lastname" value = "<?php if(isset($_POST['signup'])) { echo $_POST['lastname']; } ?>" placeholder="Презиме" required></div>
            <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="number" name="phonenumber" value = "<?php if(isset($_POST['signup'])) { echo $_POST['phonenumber']; } ?>" placeholder="Контакт Телефон" required></div>
            <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" value = "<?php if(isset($_POST['signup'])) { echo $_POST['password']; } ?>" placeholder="Лозинка" required></div>
            <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="password" name="cpassword" value = "<?php if(isset($_POST['signup'])) { echo $_POST['cpassword']; } ?>" placeholder="Повтори Лозинка" required></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="form-check"><label class="form-check-label"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">Ги прифаќам правата на политика</label></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Регистрирај</button></div><a href="login.php" class="already">Постоечки корисник? Најавете се тука.</a></form>
```

This is the validation

```
<?php

include('includes/general.php');
if (isset($_POST['signup']))
{
    require "gump.class.php";
    $gump  = new GUMP;
    $_POST = $gump->sanitize($_POST);

    $gump->validation_rules([
        'email'       => 'required|valid_email',
        'username'    => 'required|alpha_numeric|max_len,20|min_len,2',
        'firstname'   => 'required|alpha|max_len,30|min_len,2',
        'lastname'    => 'required|alpha|max_len,30|min_len,1',
        'password'    => 'required|max_len,50|min_len,6',
        'phonenumber' => 'required|numeric|max_len,20|min_len,3',
    ]);
    $gump->filter_rules([
        'email'     => 'trim|sanitize_email',
        'username'  => 'trim|sanitize_string',
        'firstname' => 'trim|sanitize_string',
        'lastname'  => 'trim|sanitize_string',
        'password'  => 'trim',
    ]);
    $validated_data = $gump->run($_POST);

    if ($validated_data === false)
    {
        ?>
        <center><font color="red"> <?php echo $gump->get_readable_errors(true); ?> </font></center>
        <?php
        include('signup.php');
    }
    else if ($_POST['password'] !== $_POST['cpassword'])
    {
        echo "<center><font color='red'>Passwords do not match </font></center>";
        include('signup.php');
    }
    else
    {
        $username      = $validated_data['username'];
        $checkusername = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";
        $run_check = mysqli_query($connection, $checkusername) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($run_check);
        if ($count > 0)
        {
            echo "<center><font color='red'>username already taken! try a different one</font></center>";
            include('signup.php');
            exit();
        }
        $email     = $validated_data['email'];
        $username  = $validated_data['username'];
        $firstname = $validated_data['firstname'];
        $lastname  = $validated_data['lastname'];
        $phone     = $validated_data['phonenumber'];
        $pass      = $validated_data['password'];
        $password  = password_hash("$pass", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $query     = "INSERT INTO users(email,username,firstname,lastname,phonenumber,password) VALUES ('$email' , '$username', '$firstname' , '$lastname', '$phone', '$password')";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
        if (mysqli_affected_rows($connection) > 0)
        {
            echo "<script>alert('SUCCESSFULLY REGISTERED');
    window.location.href='index.php';</script>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<script>alert('An error occured, Try again!');
    window.location.href='signup.php';</script>";
        }
    }
}
else
{

    header('location: signup.php');
}

?>
```

The validation and the register form are connected. I tried to find misspelling or a wrongly defined variable but with no luck. The sad thing is i don't get any errors that's why I'm having a hard time figuring out what the problem is.

Comment: Looks like there's no element with name `signup` in your form, thus `if(isset($_POST['signup'])) {` doesn't get triggered.

Comment: Are you sure you're passing $_POST['signup'] somewhere?

Comment: @kerbholz signup is the name of the file form. What should i put there? I pass the variable name later in the same line of code. That is to check if the field on the form is filled out.

Comment: "_signup is the name of the file form._" ? What file form? Your `<form>` doesn't have a `name` attribute. You could name your submit button and check for that.

Comment: instead of `isset($_POST['signup'])` use `isset($_POST)` and change pass hash function `password_hash("$pass", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);` to `password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);`

Comment: @kerbholz the file that the form is contained with. signup.php

Comment: Ok, that sounds like you should first get to know the basics of PHP form handling. Please consult your favorite search engine on "PHP form handling"

Comment: @kerbholz Sorry for the late response i was rather busy. I came here because i already tried google and didn't find an explanation or a solution. If you can point out my problem sure but i didn't came here to hear from people that i need to use google.

Comment: An explanation was already given by me and Alberto, there is no `$_POST['signup']` in your form